# LINQ To SQL exception with Attach(): Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, concurrency, datacontext

Consider this typical disconnected scenario:

- load a Customer object from SQL Server using LINQ To SQL
- user edits the entity, and the presentation tier sends back the entity modified.
- the data layer, using L2S, must send the changes to SQL Server

Consider this LINQ To SQL query whose intention is to take a Customer entity.

```
Cust custOrig = db.Custs.SingleOrDefault(o => o.ID == c.ID); //get the original
db.Custs.Attach(c, custOrig); //we don't have a TimeStamp=True property
db.SubmitChanges();
```

> `DuplicateKeyException: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.`

[image]

**Question**

- How can you avoid this exception?
- What's the best strategy for updating an entity that does NOT have/want/need a timestamp property?

**Sub-Optimal Workarounds**

- manually set each property in the updated customer to the orig customer.
- spin up another DataContext

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that your datacontext (db) cannot track the same entity more than once. See [this post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/135659.aspx) for more details on what's going on.

One of the obscure comments at the bottom of that post says to try:

```
public void Update(Customer customer)
{
  NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext();
  context.Attach(customer);
  context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, customer);
  context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Let me know how it works out for you, as the OP of that post says it worked out for him...

Comment: +1; thanks! That did indeed work! I'll leave this question 'unanswered' for now, but this answer definitely solves the problem!

Comment: As JustLoren says Attach is there for giving a context an entity it doesn't yet have - it can't be used to replace one. In a typical situation if you are getting an object back it is sometime later and will be attached to a new data context.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of creating a new context you could do this:

```
public void Update(Customer customer)
{
    Customer oldCustomer= db.Custs.First(c => c.ID == customer.ID);  //retrieve unedited 
    oldCustomer = customer;  // set the old customer to the new customer.
    db.SubmitChanges();  //sumbit to database
}
```

Comment: That won't update the database, it will just change what the variable oldCustomer refers to.