# Linq 2 SQL : update record via a web service

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a business class. In this business class there are :

1. a context to access database (via .dbml)
2. Some methods

A `SaveUser(User user)` method from this business class is called by a webservice. This method receive the modified `User` object. How can I update the record in the database by the value from the object receive as parameter (the fields value have the expected values) ?

I tried this :

```
context.Users.Attach(user); 
context.SubmitChanges();
```

I tried without the last line, same... no change in the database.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

**Update 1**

```
public class RightManager
    {
        private readonly DBDataContext dc;

        public RightManager()
        {
            dc = new DBDataContext();
        }

        public User GetUser(int id)
        {
            User user = dc.GetTable<User>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == id && x.IsEnable == true)
                .SingleOrDefault<User>();

            return user;
        }                     

        public void SaveUser(User user)
        {
            dc.Users.Attach(user);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Some code would be welcome, we can't really see what you're doing wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Please see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1758214/31136

Comment: @brunoconde I tried that, no change in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the object you recieve by argument is not User object. You have to get one from context (usually by Id), update required properties and submit then.

```
public void SaveUser (User user) {
    var userToUpdate = context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == user.Id).Single();
    userToUpdate.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    userToUpdate.LastName = user.LastName;

    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the overload of the attach method.

See this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2007/10/08/attach-if-you-have-something-detached.aspx